# how to use cmake to generate visual studio at specified build directory

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have cmake 2.8.2. and a project with directory like this: In the repository, I have `bin` directory to store built binary files. I can generate visual studio solution files in `bin` folder without any problem with `cmake-gui`. But I'd like to generate solution file using the command line version of cmake.

I tried `cmake -G "Visual Studio 9 2008" ..` in `bin` directory, but solution file is generated in the repository directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you have

```
Repository/CMakeLists.txt
Repository/srcs...
```

and you create a bin directory in Repository:

```
cd Repository
mkdir bin
cd bin
```

then you can do what you want:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 9 2008" ..
```

and it will work.

Comment: I didn't delete cmakecache neither. so subsequent cmake call generated solution file in place instead of in `bin` folder

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, simply running 
    cmake -G"Visual Studio 9 2008" ..
while in your bin directory should work.

However, if there is still a CMakeCache.txt file from earlier "in-source" build, this will not work. Is there a CMakeCache.txt in the .. directory? Is so, remove it and try again...